# How to load programmatically a layout XML file in Android?

Tags: android, layout

I have made a layout (say **my_layout.xml**) which includes programmatically two other XML layout files, say **some_layout.xml** and **another_layout.xml**. **my_layout.xml** is drawn using `setContentView(R.layout.my_layout)`.

Now I have a checkbox with ID `some_checkbox`, which is defined inside **some_layout.xml**, and I want to give the checkbox an `OnCheckedChangeListener` using `setOnCheckedChangeListener()`, just like this:

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.some_checkbox);
cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    ...
});
```

But now a `NullPointerException` is thrown, because `cb` is `null`. I guess that's because the layout containing `some_checkbox` (which is **some_layout**) is not loaded using `setContentView(R.layout.some_layout)`.

- Question 1: Why? Why returns finding `R.id.some_checkbox` `null`? **some_layout** really *is* visible.
- Question 2: How do I 'load' **some_layout** so I can capture `some_layout` into a variable, like I tried in the code snippet above?

### UPDATE

I've finally solved it, using the following, suggested by [stealthjong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1627730/stealthjong):

> One solution could be initialising the `checkedChangeListener`, adding a listener to your expandable listview, and when a child of the expandable listview is opened, checking if your `Checkbox` is one of the inflated children, and adding the `checkedchangeListener` if so.

I've created a method called `setCheckedChangeListenerToElement(int resourceId, OnCheckedChangeListener listener)`, which saves the given resourceId (which is the ID of the element where to attach a listener to), and the given listener. Once the inflater calls the method `getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`, the View can be retrieved. Then, on that View, `findViewById(int resourceId)` can be called, where `resourceId` is the ID of the checkbox.

Comment: This is, of course, not normal. Sorry for the, maybe stupid question, but, have you tried cleaning the project?

Comment: I tried. It didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried finding the `some_layout` from the root view first and then searching for a checkbox from that object?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are two approaches for this.

The first being adding child layouts through XML:

**1.  XML approach**

`my_layout.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/child_layout1" >
    </include>

    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/child_layout2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And `child_layout1` and `child_layout2` are just two other layouts, the second having a `Button` with id `mbutton`.

Your application entry should look like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
        View v = findViewById(R.id.mbutton);
        System.out.println(v == null);
        System.out.println(v.getClass().getName());
    }   
}
```

this nets me a `false` and a `android.widget.Button`, exactly as I suspected.

**2. Programmatical approach**

The other approach is the programmatical approach, and since you described it as such, I suspect this is what you did (or at least tried to):

`noinclude_layout.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/inclusionlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And a slightly larger application entrypoint:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.noinclude_layout);
        ViewGroup inclusionViewGroup = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.inclusionlayout);

        View child1 = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
                R.layout.child_layout1, null); 
        View child2 = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
                R.layout.child_layout2, null);
        inclusionViewGroup.addView(child1);
        inclusionViewGroup.addView(child2);

        View v = findViewById(R.id.mbutton);
        System.out.println(v == null);
        System.out.println(v.getClass().getName());
    }   
}
```

Which also nets me a `false` and a `android.widget.Button`.

Either solution should work just fine.

**UPDATE**

Your `expandableListView` is the problem, since the childLayout is not inflated until you actually open/expand the section (see code below for small piece of code to check current viewtree).

One solution could be initialising the `checkedChangeListener`, adding a listener to your expandable listview, and when a child of the expandable listview is opened, checking if your `Checkbox` is one of the inflated children, and adding the `checkedchangeListener` if so.

A probably more straightforward approach would be this one:

```
<CheckBox
    ...
    android:onClick="checkclicked" />
```

and in your `Activity`, add the method `public void checkclicked(View view){ ... }`

**ViewTree printer**

```
private void printFullTree() {
    printTree(this.getWindow().getDecorView(),0);
}

private void printTree(View view, int indent) {
    System.out.print(indent(indent) + view.getClass().getName() + "; " + view.getId());
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)view;
        System.out.print("; children = " + vg.getChildCount() + "\n");
        for (int i = 0; i< vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
            printTree(vg.getChildAt(i), indent++);
        }
    }
    else
        System.out.print("\n");
}

private String indent(int indent) {
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < indent; i++) {
        result += "  ";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

If some_layout.xml is included in my_layout.xml using the include tag, such as:-

```
<include layout="@layout/some_layout" android:id="@+id/someLayoutId" />
```

Then you can do the following:-

```
View someLayoutView = findViewById(R.id.someLayoutId);
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) someLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.some_checkbox);
```

If you inflated some_layout.xml programatically, such as:-

```
View someLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                    R.layout.some_layout, null);
```

Then you can still do as above:-

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) someLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.some_checkbox);
```